# Handling API errors vs Network errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am building an SDK.

Basically developers pass in a error Handler function that will be called with the error that occurs when making an API call.

For API errors (or errors returned by the API), I create an NSError with domain ExampleAPPDomain.
ApI Errors have a different userInfo structure (I add a "category" key to the user info, for example).

But sometimes the error is a nsurlconnection error ... I also pass that error to the error handler.

so I call:

```
errorHandler(error)
```

sometimes the NSError error passed into errorHandler function is an API error and sometimes it is a NSUrlConnection type error (like a network error).

How can I best handle those errors differently?
For example, in the error handler code, developers would have to check the domain for the Error to see what type it is (NSURLDomain vs ExampleAPPDomain) and handle it accordingly. That is the only way to differently between both errors.

What is the standard way of handling APP errors vs NSUrlConnection connected errors for something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not always give them ExampleAppDomain as the domain of the error. In that ways there is no confusion. Most of the standard libraries do this - encapsulate all errors. Essentially, when you get the error back you need to wrap that with your domain in NSError. You can check for an acceptable statusCode AND content of the NSURLConnectionDelegate of the response. Also, instead of dealing with all the network codes yourself, why not use standard libraries like AFNetworking ?

Here is a code, but you have to check for acceptable codes/content based on XML/JSON. The following is an excerpt from AFNetworking.

```
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[userInfo setValue:self.responseString forKey:NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestionErrorKey];
[userInfo setValue:[self.request URL] forKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLErrorKey];
[userInfo setValue:self.request forKey:ExampleAppDomainFailingURLRequestErrorKey];
[userInfo setValue:self.response forKey:ExampleAppDomainOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey];


NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:ExampleAppDomain code:NSURLErrorBadServerResponse userInfo:userInfo];
```

Check NSURLError.h file for more error info.

Comment: How should I convert the error from the NSUrlDomain to this new format? Do I just copy over the localized description and error code? or should I store the nsurldomain error as the underlying_error parameter in the userinfo of the new ExampleAppDomain error created...